# Is it possible to publish multiple versions of Lambda using SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I've a question regarding AutoPublishAlias property in SAM.

I'm looking for a way to publish multiple lambda versions and use API gateway stage variables to control access specific lambda function versions as explained in the following blog post.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-stage-variables-to-manage-lambda-functions/

But with AutoPublishAlias property it looks like only one lambda version can exist at a time. How do I cater to this requirement with SAM or should I be using aws cli to publish version and alias in this case?

PS: I've already reviewed the following question which has a similar requirement.

[Is it possible to configure different API Gateway stages with different lambda versions using AWS SAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57306067/is-it-possible-to-configure-different-api-gateway-stages-with-different-lambda-v)

Comment: I decided to create a new stack for dev, dev2, vs prod.  This was mostly because I'm always updating other things (pools, clients, CF, dynamodb tables) as I develop and versioning a lambda wont always mean I can version those other things.